# I want to order object within a group in Linq, based on a string and a int

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a Exercise object that has both an ID and a Category. For the purpose of this question, let's pretend it looks like this:

```
public class Exercise
{
    public int ID;
    public string category;
}
```

The ID's are unique, categories are not.

I want to use Linq to group the exercises by category, before sorting the exercises within each category based on their ID. The order of the categories should also be based on the IDs, the category of the first exercise should always be the first category after grouping the exercises. (In other words, the order of the groups should be determined by the ID's of the first object in each group, the order of those ID's should match the order of the groups.)

Example:

```
{ ID: 1, category: "C#" }
{ ID: 2, category: "ASP" }
{ ID: 3, category: "C#" }
```

The object with ID's 1 and 3 should come before the object with ID 2, eventhough ASP would come before C# alphabetically.

This is my LINQ code:

```
_db.Exercise.GroupBy(item => item.category)
            .OrderBy(group => group.FirstOrDefault().ID)
            .SelectMany(group => group)
            .ToList();
```

It puts the exercises in groups like I expect them to, but the order of the groups is alphabetical, no matter what I seem to do. I expect the OrderBy on the groups to order the groups, but alas.

I tried putting the OrderBy in different places, but without success. Also using just OrderBy doesn't seem to work. GroupBy with both the ID and the category as keys doesn't seem to work, either.

Can anyone please help me? It's my first time I try something this "advanced" in LINQ. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does removing `.FirstOrDefault()` help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get what you want by just ordering by `ID` then grouping by `Category`:

```
_db.Exercise.OrderBy(item => item.ID)
            .GroupBy(item => item.category)
            .SelectMany(group => group)
            .ToList();
```

Results:

```
List<> (3 items)
ID   category 
---- ---------
1    C# 
3    C# 
2    ASP
```

Since according to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx) the groups are returned *in the order in which the keys appear in the list*, the groups will be ordered based on the first ID in each group.

As @Servy points out, since the order of the groups is an implementation detail, you could *explicitly* order the groups:

```
_db.Exercise.OrderBy(item => item.ID)
            .GroupBy(item => item.category)
            .OrderBy(g => g.First().ID)
            .SelectMany(group => group)
            .ToList();
```

Comment: You can just use `OrderBy` followed by `ThenBy` to do this in a much less contrived manor that isn't dependent on implementation details.

Comment: @Servy the results will be different - Based on the sample data, if you order by Category then by ID, Item 2 (ASP) will come first.  If you order by ID, then by Category, The C# items will be broken up.

Comment: @Servy - and at least it's a _documented_ implementation detail. :)

Comment: I accepted this answer because it worked with my test data, but not with my real data (different classes). So that's something new to figure out, at least I now know the LINQ query should work fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you call `OrderBy` on an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<...>>` you're *ordering the groups*.  What it sounds like you want to do is to leave all of the groups in the same order, and *project each group into a new group in which the items are ordered*.  Use `Select` to project each group to a new group, and then `OrderBy` to order the group itself:

```
var query = _db.Exercise.GroupBy(item => item.category)
    .Select(group => group.OrderBy(item => item.ID));
```

If, on the other hand, you just want to order by category first, and then ID, just use `OrderBy` and `ThenBy`:

```
var query = _db.Exercise.OrderBy(item => item.category)
    .ThenBy(item => item.ID);
```

Comment: I think you want `SelectMany`?

Comment: @Aducci If he wants to flatten the collection he can.  Clearly that's an operation he already knows how to use if he wants to.  I would generally find the first solution useful if he *didn't* want to flatten the collection.  If he did, it is probably more correct to just not use that solution.

Answer (score 0):

`groupId` - Lowest ID for all Exercise's with the same category

Once you have that, it is a simple order by

```
var query = from e in _db.Exercise
            let groupId = _db.Exercise.Where(x => x.category == e.category).Select(x => x.ID).Min()
            order by groupId, e.ID
            select e;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
List<Exercise> selectMany = _db.Exercise.GroupBy(exercise => exercise.category)
                                        .SelectMany(grouping => 
                                                    grouping.OrderBy(e => e.ID))
                               .ToList();
```